# How do I remotely connect to a windows XP virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop, windows-xp

I'm running Windows XP on a virtual machine (Orace VirtualBox 4.0.8) on a home server and I want to be able to connect to it from outside the network. I have the domain thanks to dyndns.com which points to the computer and the router is port-forwarded to the server computer. But am I supposed to forward to the server or the virtual machine's IP? Now when I try to connect I get an error: failed to connect.

And how does these authentication methods work: null, external, guest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To connect to the services, you'll have to have a address on the local area network and not on a private "bridged" interface for the virtual machine.

- Open Virtual Box
- shutdown the Windows virtual machine if it's running
- right-click on the virtual machine and select settings
- Select Network and for Attached to: select Bridged Adaptor

Your virtual host should now have an address from the main network. Forward the ports to this address. And probably configure an appropriate static address in Windows.

Comment: Just to add, in general, you *need* a wired connection to the router for bridged mose.

Answer (score 2):

If the virtual machine has an IP from the local network, you can connect via Samba, WWW, or rdesktop

If the virtual machine has an IP of the host's internal "Default" network, e.g., 192.168.122.x, you'll only be able to connect via VNC.

To connect via VNC, add new graphics hardware to the VM in Virtual Machine Manager, telling it to listen on all public interfaces.  You can then forward a port from your router to the host's IP address, with the port listed in virt-manager, usually something like 5901.

-Eric

Comment: Downvote, sorry but this is wrong. He is using VirtualBox and you are answering like he is using KVM. This is going to confuse the user.

Comment: Good point! Missed that part completely.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what connect means here. But if you are trying to connect to your VM using Remote Desktop then you have to forward the 3389 port on you router to the *host* ip (where host is the computer running the virtual machine, not the one running on the VM).

You will also need to have installed the Oracle Extension Pack and have enabled RDP in the Virtual Machine settings.

[image]

Sorry for the spanish screenshot, I hope that you find the place in your own language.

About the authentication:

- **None** means that there is no authentication, the system will let you connect the same way that a local screen, i.e. it will only ask for a password if you are not logged or you had blocked the screen.
- **Extrenal** uses some external method to authenticate. In a linux host that means that you will need to use a PAM server. Not really useful for personal use. One note: you can use this to hook into your own authentication lib, which is really geeky.
- **Guest** uses your guest authentication system. If you are running a windows guest, that means that it will always ask you for your windows user and password to let you log in. This is the easiest way, but you will need to have the Guest Additions running on your guest to be able to use it.

You can find much more info in the [user manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vbox-auth).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response but I can still not make it work. I can't find any detailed tutorials on the issue. Am I supposed to assign the guest with it's own ip (Network = "bridged adaptor") or just go with the "NAT" option? With the server running, should I connect to the guest IP or the host IP?

Comment: It should work with any network setup, you should connect to the guest IP.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your virtual machine and click `settings` then go to `networks` tab and then change the `Attached to:` setting to `Bridged Adapter` default is `NAT`.
Then start your virtual machine and you have an ip reference to the virtual machine from your network so just install vnc server on the vm like [ultravnc](http://www.ultravnc.com) and you're good.